# SQL Compare Column names from one table with values from another if a specific condition for the values of table 2 is met

Tags: sql, mariadb

The question may be a bit weird...
I am working with two tables:

```
MariaDB [criticaldb]> select * from commands;
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| cmd_id | command  | description                                                                                                    |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      1 | help     | Provides a list of available commands.                                                                         |
|      2 | announce | Generates an announcement of the message specified after the command.                                          |
|      3 | hotfix   | Prints a hotfix of the message specified after the command.                                                    |
|      4 | change   | Prints a changelog of the message specified after the command.                                                 |
|      5 | quote    | Generates a quote for the mentioned person with a custom string of text.                                       |
|      6 | embed    | Generates an embed with an ID. use `embed create ID`. Embeds and their IDs are saved in `./dicts/embeds.json`. |
|      7 | hug      | Use this command to hug someone or to demand hugs from others.                                                 |
|      8 | ttt      | Challenge another member to a game of Tic Tac Toe!                                                             |
+--------+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

MariaDB [criticaldb]> select * from permissions;
+--------------------+------+------+------+------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+------+-------+------+
| server_id          | warn | mute | kick | ban  | announce | changelog | embed | help | hotfix | hug  | quote | ttt  |
+--------------------+------+------+------+------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+------+-------+------+
| 846354366851448842 |    2 |    2 |    3 |    4 |        4 |         4 |     4 |    1 |      4 |    0 |     0 |    0 |
+--------------------+------+------+------+------+----------+-----------+-------+------+--------+------+-------+------+
```

What I am trying to do is the following: Ignoring cmd_id from the commands table, I'd want command, description from the commands table to be selected, if for the command in the permissions table a certain condition is met, e.g. value of command in permissions table <=3.

So in this case, the selection I'd like as a result would be

```
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| command  | description                                                                                                    |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| help     | Provides a list of available commands.                                                                         |

| quote    | Generates a quote for the mentioned person with a custom string of text.                                       |
| hug      | Use this command to hug someone or to demand hugs from others.                                                 |
| ttt      | Challenge another member to a game of Tic Tac Toe!                                                             |
+----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I hope this is possible. I've been able to "convert" the column names of the permissions table into column values of a selection like this:

```
MariaDB [criticaldb]> select COLUMN_NAME from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = N'permissions';
+-------------+
| COLUMN_NAME |
+-------------+
| server_id   |
| warn        |
| mute        |
| kick        |
| ban         |
| announce    |
| changelog   |
| embed       |
| help        |
| hotfix      |
| hug         |
| quote       |
| ttt         |
+-------------+
```

I hope I am asking nothing impossible, and I would appreciate any answer!

Comment: It's not possible without using dynamic SQL to build a query. I would suggest you consider reformatting `permissions` to have only 3 columns, `server_id, command, permissions`, then this becomes trivial. It's generally relatively easy to pivot that form of data to generate the look of your current permissions table (if that is required) in your application software.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you. I think that is a good alternative to what I've been trying for over 2 hours.